# Correct syntax for using echo in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, echo

I run this code, and got this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in C:\xampp\htdocs\Generate.php on line 5
```

What is the problem?

```
<?php
$satr=$_POST["satr"];
$soton=$_POST["soton"];
$bg=$_POST["bg"];
echo ("<table border="1" style="background-color:$bg">");
for($i=1;&i<=$satr;$i++)
{
    echo("<tr>");
    for($j=1;j<=$soton;$j++)
    {
        echo("<td>$soton</td>");
}
echo("</tr>");
}
echo("</table>");    

?>
```

Comment: Use `sprintf()`: `echo sprintf('<table border="1" style="background-color:%s">', $bg);`

Comment: Use `$i<=$satr;` insted of `&i<=$satr;`

Comment: @MikeBrant  even with syntax highlighting he'd need to understand why its an error.

Comment: @TobyAllen The answer below give you that information.  You have a quote escaping problem.

Comment: echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 2):

```
    echo ("<table border='1' style='background-color:$bg'>");

    echo ('<table border="1" style="background-color:$bg">');

    echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"background-color:$bg\">";

    echo '<table border="1" style="background-color:$bg">';

    echo "<table border='1' style='background-color:$bg'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the parenthesis and you need to escape you inner double quotes

```
<?php
$satr=$_POST["satr"];
$soton=$_POST["soton"];
$bg=$_POST["bg"];
echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"background-color:$bg\">";
for($i=1;&i<=$satr;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=1;j<=$soton;$j++)
    {
        echo "<td>$soton</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Also look here [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, you have used `&i` in **for** loop, you need to use `$i`

```
    $satr=$_POST["satr"];
    $soton=$_POST["soton"];
    $bg=$_POST["bg"];
    echo ("<table border='1' style='background-color:$bg'>");

    for($i=1;$i<=$satr;$i++)
    {
        echo("<tr>");
        for($j=1;j<=$soton;$j++)
        {
            echo("<td>$soton</td>");
        }

    echo("</tr>");
    }
    echo("</table>");
```

Comment: What is the reason for Downvote Mr.Downvoter?

Answer (score -2):

You are not escaping the quotes in the string. You need to do something like this:

```
echo ("<table border=\"1\" style=\"background-color:$bg\">");
```